# Laravel 5.5 - access storage images with no creating sym link - throws 400 error

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

routes.php

```
Route::get('img/{filename}', 'FilesController@show')->name('files.show');
```

my FilesController

```
public function show($filename)
{
    if (!Storage::exists('img/' . $filename))
    {
        return 'error'; //file exist, this is never executes
    }
    $file = Storage::get('img/' . $filename); // this line breaks
    dd($file);

    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

the Storage::get('img/' . $filename) throws error 400 on page...
the path is good...

I dont want public link because I want images to be private and to access only via controller...

Comment: Check the permissions on the file.

Comment: I checked permissions, as for images in /public/images folder...
And I can access to them via url (example : http://localhost:8000/images/Dusan_RO8ujk2LVHuXH06F.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must return `response` object from your controller action. But you return `string` in `if`.

Second, you return wrong response for downloading. Browser not understand your response, for this reason you get 400 error. For downloading files use `response()->download(...)` function.

Comment: if statement condition is false (which tells that file exists), so if statement is never executes...
And that response in if statement is for testing purpose...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I didn't store image content on my server.

I just store name with no content.

Following code returns image.

```
public function show($filename)
{
    $storage = Storage::disk('local');

    if (!$storage->exists($filename)) {
        return 'error';
    }

    $file = $storage->get($filename);
    $type = $storage->mimeType($filename);

    return new Response($file, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => $type
    ]);
}
```

thanks for help, anyway :)